# It is possible to get access to the SSMS Intellisense?

Tags: ssms, add-in, visual-studio-addins, ssms-2012, ssms-addin

I'd like to add synonyms to the SSMS Intellisense.
How can i get access to the standart SSMS Intellisense in my own Addin?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

there is currently no method to get external access to SSMS intellisense. You can file a [Connect bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback) to request this functionality.

In the meantime, you can take a look at [DbForge's SQLComplete](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/sqlcomplete/features.html#group1) to get better IntelliSense support.